# Macbook Pro 2011 stuck on white screen, while Windows 10 completely boots

Tags: windows-10, macbook-pro, boot-camp, bootable-media, white-screen

MacBook Pro (early 2011) has a white screen problem. I booted it with Windows 10 USB installer and formatted the HDD completely. It works fine (I haven't installed any driver yet), but it stuck at white screen during installing macOS with USB (after loading bar). It seems there is no hardware failure because Windows can boot itself, but still I cannot figure that what's the problem with macOS.

Comment: If you formatted with the Windows installer your macOS partitions are gone. You'll need to reformat from the macOS boot USB, or use Internet Recovery. Windows will have assumed NTFS, possibly on MBR on a Mac that old, so the entire drive is potentially the wrong format.

Comment: Thanks, but Internet Recovery is also going white. I guess it's because macOS won't use Intel Graphics in setups and AMD graphic is broken. but windows can run itself with Intel Graphic..

Comment: It has nothing to do with your graphics, you deleted all MacOS related files during windows installation. As pointed out by @Tetsujin you need to create a MacOS boot USB and do a reinstallation

Comment: It might be because the firmware update was never applied to use IR [those Macs couldn't do it out of the box] so you'll need to get the USB stick working.

Comment: @mashuptwice I cannot path through macOS USB installation because of white screen. In windows 10 or maybe CMD, is there any way to force hardware to use IG all times even during boot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the mac to boot from USB again. Make sure you have a USB install, and verify it on another mac if possible. If you know your install media works, insert the USB drive and hold down option whilst powering on, and keep holding until you see the boot selection screen. Select the USB device to begin reinstall

Comment: I did test the USB on another mac, it works. but the main problem is white screen. it won't let me to path through installation.